# Git pull is aborting even after hard reset

Tags: git, github, gitlab

```
$git pull

Updating 08f6632..e29f7b0
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
  file.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Which would be fine. Sure some files are different.
`git reset --hard`
Now no changes should exist.

Now when we run pull we expect no changes to exist.

```
$git pull

Updating 08f6632..e29f7b0
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
  file.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Dose someone know what is causing this / and how to fix it.

Comment: `git clean -df`? But `git stash -u` is safer.

Comment: If nothing else helps, do a fresh clone and copy over the changes you need manually.

Comment: What does `git status` tell you about that file? And more details can sometimes be gotten with `git diff file.txt`

Comment: We need to know more about these "local changes" to `file.txt`. It's not clear why `git reset --hard` is not *erasing* these changes, but there are at least two possibilities: you've just hidden them from us. (One possibility: two files with different casing, such as `FILE.txt` vs `file.TXT`. Another: CRLF line endings. The `git status` and `git diff` results would be helpful.)

Comment: @torek `git status` reports that the file was modified, right after the reset. Which is odd. I didnt touch any of these files. And `git diff` reports changes of the filemode from `100644` to `100755`. Which is kinda odd bcs i didnt `chmod` any of these

Comment: Aha, the fact that `git diff` says the file changed from not-executable (`100644`) to executable (`100755`) is probably the key here. Either something (not you) is running around behind your back `chmod`-ing files, or you're on a file system that doesn't respect `chmod` requests. Git tries to autodetect such file systems at `git init` time, on the theory that your file system won't change behavior afterward. But if your file system *did* change behavior, that's when you need to use `git config core.filemode false` or `git config core.filemode true`.

Comment: The `core.filemode` setting *informs* Git. It says: *if you, Git, `chmod` a file, it stays chmod-ed* (`true`), or *if you chmod a file it doesn't stick* (`false`). When set to `false`, Git trusts the `git update-index --chmod=` setting instead of the file system's setting.

Answer (score 1):

You have non committed work. To make sure you don't loose part of your work, Git doen't allow you the operation of `git pull` (which is equivalent to `git fetch` and then `git merge`).
If you want to save your progress I suggest to create a new commit and then you can pull.
The other way is to use `git stash` to temporarily store uncommitted work in order to clean out your working directory, without performing a new commmit.

Comment: yes i thought so too. But `git reset --hard` should remove all not staged changes.

Comment: Yes, the hard reset deletes all the work currently in progress. But as I can see it doesn't make what it should do.  Also, I note you try to pull without specifying which local and remote branch you want to pull.  Follow the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)